# Edit* editing a class attribute with a method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the vague question.  I'm rewriting it so I hope this helps.
I am trying to edit two attributes(which are dictionaries): a and b.
b is directly related to a (.8).

```
class Fun:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.a = {1: ["a", 10]}
        self.b = {2: ["b", 8]}
    def change(self):
        for i in self.a:
            self.a[i][1] = math.floor(random.gauss(self.a[i][1]), 5)
        self.b = copy.deepcopy(self.a)
        for i in self.b:
            self.b[i][1] = math.floor(self.a[i][1] * 0.8)
```

When I run through a loop that changes a and b, it works once then crashes with

```
"str" object has no attribute "a"
```

If it is the function that is calling it (which it could be), let me know.
Should this work to change a and b each iteration based on their current values though?

I hope this was more clear as to what I was asking for.

Comment: Which part of it is supposed to change anything you have access to?

Comment: and what's your issue?

Comment: @Faller, Why do you change the question dramatically. That make my answer obsolete. :(

Answer (score 2):

You are creating local variable `sell_price`, which does not affect sell_price outside `cahnge_price` function.

Return `sell_price` in `change_price`. Assign return value of `change_price` to outside `sell_price` explicitly.

```
def change_prices():
    for i in price:
        price[i][1] = math.floor(random.gauss(price[i][1], 5))
    sell_price = copy.deepcopy(price)
    for i in sell_price:
        sell_price[i][1] = math.floor(price[i][1] * .8)
    return sell_price

price = {1: ["Spices", 43], 2: ["Something else",50]}
sell_price = change_prices()
```

Or declare sell_price as global variable

```
def change_prices():
    global sell_price
    for i in price:
        price[i][1] = math.floor(random.gauss(price[i][1], 5))
    sell_price = copy.deepcopy(price)
    for i in sell_price:
        sell_price[i][1] = math.floor(price[i][1] * .8)

price = {1: ["Spices", 43], 2: ["Something else",50]}
sell_price = change_prices()
```